# Using find to delete all files (without sub dir)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is the structure of my dir:

```
./archive
    /sub1
        - file1
        - file2
    /sub2
        - file3
        - file4
```

I try with this command to find all the files that older than 6 months to delete it:

```
find ./archive -mindepth 1 -mtime +180 -delete
```

All the files and sub directory is deleted, what I want just the `file1, file2, file3, file4` that delete, not include the `sub1` and `sub2`, please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` supports the `-type` option. Use that to specify regular file with `f` as the argument.

```
find ./archive -mindepth 1 -mtime +180 -delete -type f
```

Answer (score 3):

include a `-type f` flag that restricts the find to only files:

```
find ./archive -mindepth 1 -mtime +180 -delete -type f
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `-type f` option to exclude directories:

```
find ./archive -mindepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f -delete
```